# grid lines - how to contain within the first quadrant

Tags: tikz-pgf, grids

As you can see from the screenshot of the output, the grid lines extend through the tick labels. How would you keep the grey grid lines within the first quadrant?

Many thanks

[image: output]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{THEOREM}
\newtheorem{proof}{PROOF}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\newenvironment{tightcenter}{
\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
\begin{center}}{\end{center}}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{options/.code={\tikzset{#1}}} % just to compact the code
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\textbf{Question 1} (5 marks)\\[0.124cm]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=middle,
grid=major,
xmin=-1,
xmax=11,
ymin=-1,
ymax=13,
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel=$y$,
xtick={0,1,...,10},
ytick={0,1,...,12},
scale=1.9,
transform shape,
tick style={very thick},
legend style={
at={(rel axis cs:0,1)},
anchor=north west,draw=none,inner sep=0pt,fill=gray!10}
]
%
%line of best fit
\plot[thick,samples=150,domain=0:10] {1.2*x-0.8};
\end{axis}
\newline
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How about just setting `xmin=0,ymin=0`?

Comment: Oh wow, that worked perfectly! How do I put your suggestion as a solution? :)

Comment: I just wrote a quick answer. To make it more worthwhile, I also commented on the general solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{options/.code={\tikzset{#1}}} % just to compact the code
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\textbf{Question 1} How to remove the grid left of the $y$- and below the
$x$--axis\\[0.124cm]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=middle,
grid=major,
xmin=0,
xmax=11,
ymin=0,
ymax=13,
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel=$y$,
xtick={0,1,...,10},
ytick={0,1,...,12},
scale=1.9,
transform shape,
tick style={very thick},
legend style={
at={(rel axis cs:0,1)},
anchor=north west,draw=none,inner sep=0pt,fill=gray!10}
]
%
%line of best fit
\plot[thick,samples=150,domain=0:10] {1.2*x-0.8};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}


\textbf{Question 2} How to prevent the grid from running through the ticks\\[0.124cm]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=middle,
grid=major,
xmin=-3,
xmax=6,
ymin=-3,
ymax=6,
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel=$y$,
xtick={-2,-1,...,5},
ytick={-2,-1,...,7},
scale=1.9,
transform shape,
ticklabel style={
            fill=white
        },
tick style={very thick},
legend style={
at={(rel axis cs:0,1)},
anchor=north west,draw=none,inner sep=0pt,fill=gray!10}
]
%
%line of best fit
\plot[thick,samples=150,domain=-3:6] {1.2*x-0.8};
\end{axis}
\newline
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What if one wishes to display some area below the x axis and to the left of the y axis, as in the original question?